# how do i convert my json response to a txt tab delimited file rest api java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have a sql query.

this is my abc.class

```
public class Abc {
    
    private Integer ABC_ID;
    private String RECIP_ID, RECIP_FIRST_NAME, RECIP_MIDDLE_NAME;
    
    public Abc() {
        //super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    }
```

and the rest are the getters and setters;

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<List<abc>> getProviderExport(@RequestParam String id, HttpServletResponse response){
    
List<abc> abcdetails = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<abc>(abc.class));
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        //responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        String filename1 = "output.txt";
        //responseHeaders.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+filename1);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(abcdetails, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

when I execute the above code and run the api, my api prompts to save the output file as output.txt, but when i open the output file, the content is still in json format. can anyone help me on how to achieve the output.txt file that is using tab delimited and uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you return `ResponseEntity<List<abc>>`. A `List<>` is converted automatically to array JSON. You need to return a `ResponseEntity<String>`. So, convert your `List<abc>` to `String`.

Something like this :

```
final StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();
for (final Abc abcDetail : abcdetails) {
    final String line = abcDetail.getRECIP_FIRST_NAME() + " " + abcDetail.getRECIP_ID() + " ";//You can add your other field
    textData.append(line).append("\n");
}

return new ResponseEntity<>(textData.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: @NewBond007 Can you provide in your topic the definition of your `abc` class?

Comment: @NewBond007 and how do you do to convert the `List<abc>` into `String`? If you do `abcdetails.toString()`. It is not the good way.

Comment: @NewBond007 I edit my answer. You can recheck it. I suppose `getRECIP_FIRST_NAME()` and `getRECIP_ID()` etc are the getters of your variables.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Thats not what i was looking for, but you definitely ignited the idea on how to achieve this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert that json format to text format using Jackson JSON Java Parser I am attaching a link for a brief example on how to convert jsno to txt file with tab delimited and uppercase.

Here is the link : https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial